# Is it possible to connect multiple sensors to raspberry pi? How do I expand on the standard gpio pins?

Tags: rfid

I followed the below diagram and connect the [MFRC522 RC522 RF IC Card Reader](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01M28JAAZ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) to the RPi.

[image]

And now I would like to connect 10 rfid modules to the raspberry pi. I’ve looked at two ways to do this

1. Use a [MCP23S17](https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/mcp23s17-16bit-port-expander-spi) chip
2. An IO expander board like this [IO Pi Plus](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/p/54/io-pi-plus)

The questions I have about these two choices are;

A. Will they be able to connect 10 of the above rfid readers?

B. Will I be able to see which rfid reader the data originated from?

C. Which option would be easier in terms of wiring and the code needed to read from an rfid source?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SPI or I2C?

Answer (score 4):

The Amazon link in your Q says the RFID board has both SPI and I2C interface. The RPi also has these interfaces. So far, so good. But [physical distance is a factor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163468/spi-max-distance) with these buses, and your question says exactly nothing about that.

In other words, your question *suggests* that you have not done your homework. You need to do some research, and then edit your question. After you get a handle on the distance requirement, you should do some research to understand [how I2C and SPI buses work](https://www.bluedot.space/tutorials/how-many-devices-can-you-connect-on-i2c-bus/). You will also need a better understanding of your hardware; e.g. does your RFID reader allow you to set a unique bus address on each unit?

Maybe read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help section here.